# Amazon Alexa skill say something while performing long running task

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building an Amazon Alexa skill and it's all working out quite well so far. 
I'm using c# (.net core app) and AWS lambda function. 
The problem I have is the function makes several API requests and this can take a bit of time (up to 10 seconds sometimes). I'm using the closes region for my area (that supports alexa skill trigger). My skill has only one intent that does all the work. It's the final api call that can be quite slow and this is not the greatest user experience.

Is there a way to say something to the user while fetching the required data?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Extending the the session timeout duration is not a supported feature of Alexa Skills Kit. There is unfortunately no recommended workaround for latency issues, as response times exceeding 8 seconds aren't supported. You will need to take a look at your back-end architecture to see where latency could be improved.

That said, by utilizing the Progressive Response API, you can improve the perceived latency for users by providing some interstitial content for Alexa to play while waiting for your skill's full response. If that interests you, please see the documentation here:
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/f952eca8-7f6f-4490-85d8-a805b50f6d25/alexa-skill-recipe-improving-the-perceived-latency-of-api-calls-using-the-progressive-response-api